# Previous data is undefined in update call when using API Platform Admin (React-Admin) with hydraDataProvider

Tags: react-admin, api-platform.com

We are using "API Platform" with "API Platform Admin" for the backend of our mobile app.

Our API provides a hydra data format, so we use the built-in `hydraDataProvider` of API Platform Admin to handle the API calls.

I have to overwrite the update behavior of our dataProvider to use PATCH instead of PUT, so I did the following:

```
const baseDataProvider = hydraDataProvider({
    entrypoint: ENTRYPOINT,
    httpClient: fetchHydraWithAuthentication,
    apiDocumentationParser: apiDocumentationParser
});

baseDataProvider.update = function(resource, params) {
    return this.httpClient(`${this.entrypoint}/${resource}/${params.id}`, {
        method: 'PATCH',
        body: JSON.stringify(diff(params.data, params.previousData)),
    }).then(({json}) => ({data: json}));
};
```

The `diff` function simply returns a new object which only contains the changed fields.

However, `params.previousData` is undefined when a user edits a resource and clicks the save button. I figured it may be caused by some previous error on the page where this behavior occurs, but there are no errors in the JavaScript console on that page. The first error that occurs is that `params.previousData` is undefined when the `diff` function is called.

We haven't added much custom logic, most things are done by the default implementations and automations of API Platform Admin.

What could cause this issue? Is `previousData` supposed to be empty?

Comment: I'm no API Platform expert, but looking at their [code](https://github.com/api-platform/admin/blob/main/src/EditGuesser.tsx#L124), it seems that they are not providing `previousData` when they are calling `update`. Maybe you should open an issue on their repo to request them to also provide `previousData`?